# Undefined in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, telerik

I am new to Telerik et MVC, I need some help, I am getting in the options list of the drop down list "years" Undefined instead of 2017, 2015, ...

Any help is appreciated. Below are the codes.

This is the view:

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList().Name("years")
              .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:100%" })
              .OptionLabel("Select year...")
              .DataTextField("YearName")
              .DataValueField("YearCode")
              .DataSource(source =>
              {
                  source.Read(read =>
                  {
                      read.Action("GetCascadeYears","Home");
                  });
              })
)
```

and this is the controller:

```
 public JsonResult GetCascadeYears()
        {
            IQueryable years = Year.GetYears();

            if (HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
            {
                return Json(new SelectList(
                            years,"YearCode", "YearName"), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                            );
            }

            return View(years);
        }
```

and this the model:

```
public class Year
    {

        public int YearCode { get; set; }
        public String YearName { get; set; }

        public static IQueryable<Year> GetYears()
        {
            return new List<Year>
            {
                new Year {
                    YearCode = 1,
                    YearName = "2017"
                },
                new Year{
                    YearCode = 2,
                    YearName = "2015"
                },
                new Year{
                    YearCode = 3,
                    YearName = "2014"
                },
                new Year{
                    YearCode = 4,
                    YearName = "2010"
                },

            }.AsQueryable();
        }


    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its just `return Json(years, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);` - there is no point creating a `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` and it you did, its properties are `Value` and `Text` (not `YearCode` and `YearName`)

Comment: Thank you so much, It WORKs!!